# always select "Take Photo" when running vue project on IOS (Safari)

Tags: javascript, ios, vuejs2, safari, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`. I have a `b-form-file` in my template which I'm using to upload photos - it should run on a Webbroswer and it's, for now, always used by an iPhone-User.

Now I want to know if there is a possibility that my project notice that I have opened it on Safari (it's possible that it will run on Android too later because of that it should check that first) and than if this is known it should select always *Take Photo or Video*.

Normally you can choose between these 3 on iPhone after clicking on `b-form-file`

1. Photo Libarry
2. Take Photo or Video
3. Browse

and it should always use **Take Photo or Video** after detecting that it's running on Safari..

Is it possible to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance!